# Interaction between media query, position absolute/fixed and JS onclick handler?

Tags: javascript, css

I've added a button to some pages, inside a `div` which is in a `header` element. The `header` is positioned fixed with top/left at 0 and width 100%. The `div` doesn't have a CSS position spec. For the default (mobile-first), the `button` was positioned absolute with right 32px. In a minimal screen, it sits to the left of a pure CSS, hamburger menu, which goes away (via a CSS `@media` query) once the width is 576px.

A pure JS event handler was added to handle button clicks. It's a show/hide toggle handler which changes the button's `textContent` and a CSS rule that affects other page elements. The handler works fine for all window sizes, tested on Chromium, Firefox and a tablet.

However, the button looks somewhat odd in the top right corner at larger sizes, so I added a media query as follows:

```css
@media all and (min-width: 960px) {
  .btn {
     top: 90px;
  }
}
```

This places it close to the bottom right of the `header`. The problem is that this appears to break the event handler: clicking on the button does nothing. It doesn't matter whether the screen is already at over 960px when a page is entered or whether the position changes due to resizing the window. Specifying other attributes in the media query, such as `position` and `right` have no effect and neither does using position `fixed` instead of `absolute`. Resizing to lower widths causes the handler to work again.

Is there an explanation for this strange behavior? Or is there a way around it?

UPDATE: The answer is `yes` (see comments). In essence, it's a reminder to make HTML elements "visible" (using temp background-colors) to verify if multiple elements overlap--CSS can be very deceptive).

Comment: Without a [mcve], it is not really possible to say. But the most likely reason is that another element overlaps your button and receives the click.

Comment: @t.niese Thanks. I think the overlap may be a possibility.

Comment: @t.niese You were right. There were some navbars at the bottom of the header and if I clicked just above the overlap (or changed `top` to get ihe button out of the way), the click handler works OK.